# How to implement observer pattern with generics?

Tags: java, observer-pattern

Im making a restaurant app, where I need to use Generics type parameter. The workflow is the following: The Client (Observer) orders a food (interface), and the FoodFactory makes returns the concrete type (like hotdog, chips, etc), then the Client(Observer) gets notified about it. There are classes what I **need** to use in this exercise.
In this exercise, the type parameter `<E>` is *Food*.
Abstract class Observable:

```
public abstract class Observable<E>{

List<Observer<E>> observers = new ArrayList<>();

public void abbObserver(Observer <E> e){
 observers.add(e);
}

public void notifyObservers(E e){
    for(Observer observer : observers){
        observer.update(this);
    }
}
```

}

this class is inherited by the `Order` Class.

```
public class Order<E> extends Observable<E> {

    private FoodName food;
    private List<FoodName> extras;


    public Order(FoodName food, List<FoodName> extras) {
            this.food = food;
            this.extras = extras;
    }

    public FoodName getFood() {
            return food;
    }

    public List<FoodName> getExtras() {
            return extras;
    }

    @Override
    public void abbObserver(Observer<E> e) {
            super.abbObserver(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyObservers(E e) {
            System.out.println("Notifying Observers of: " + e.toString());
    }
```

However I'm not sure how can I do this. Do I need to inherit the `List<Observer<E>> observers = new ArrayList<>();` too?
Im generally missing out in this topic, I learned it recently, however I don't understand how these objects can communicate with eachother.

Comment: You are already inheriting the `observers` list. You are also inheriting the `notifyObservers(E e)` method, so just remove the overriding method from `Order` and you have a working method. The overriding `abbObserver` method, consisting of nothing but a `super.abbObserver` call, is obsolete as well. And, by the way, the name should be `addObserver` with Ds, not Bs.

Comment: Looks like you wanted to have a `class Order extends Observable<Foodname>`, isn't it?

Comment: The exercise says in this case the <E> should be Food, however I don't understand why does that matter aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like:

```
public class FoodName {
  private final String name;

  public FoodName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

---

```
public class Order extends Observable<FoodName> {

  private FoodName food;
  private List<FoodName> extras = new ArrayList<>();

  public Order(FoodName food, List<FoodName> extras) {
    this.food = food;
    this.extras = extras;
  }

  public FoodName getFood() {
    return food;
  }

  public List<FoodName> getExtras() {
    return extras;
  }

  public void addExtras(FoodName extra) {
    extras.add(extra);
    notifyObservers(extra);
  }

}
```

---

```
public interface Observer<E> {
  void update(E e);
}
```

---

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Order order = new Order(new FoodName("bigmac"), new ArrayList<>());
    order.abbObserver(fn -> System.out.println(fn.getName()));
    order.addExtras(new FoodName("french fries"));
  }
}
```